# Laravel Auth Middleware Error Message

Tags: laravel

How to show error message when an user access an url that are protected by Laravel middleware auth (['middleware'=>'auth])?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open *app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php* and inside the **handle()** method change the condition to somethig like this:

```
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
        return redirect()->guest('login')->with(['message' => 'You should login.']);
    }
```

So then you'll have the variable *$message* in your view, you just have to output it.

Comment: From L5.4 the Authenticate class is now a part of the Laravel core: `\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate`. How to modify it?

Comment: It is possible via the exceptions handler: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-55-auth-middleware-redirect-to-login-page-can-show-some-message